# Facebook app pages api re-submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the platform update on 2018-04-24 of Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/ they mention the following "Access to the Pages APIs requires re-submission of the application for review before August 1, 2018."

My question is how does this re-submission work? currently my app is reviewed already but should I resubmit and if so, how can/should I re-submit?

Comment: App reviewed is paused. When it open up you will be able to resubmit

Answer (score 1):

In a call today with Facebook team, they told me the App Review is paused. When it start to work again (it will be announced in the blog), they will give you 90 days to re-submit your app again or you will lose your access.